# Css color bottom pixel on click

Tags: css

I am looking to color the bottom pixel (the bottom width pixel, along all the length of the image) of my image to one particular color when I click on it. I would like not to add anything in the html.
Can that be achieved only in css doing something like :

```
.image:active{
 width: 1.5px;
 background-color: my_color;
 length: 100%;
}
```

Comment: 1. What is `length`? 2. Use the `border-bottom` property. 3. Please provide your markup, for example is `.image` an `<img />` or `<button>` element?

Comment: U can be achieved it by using javascript also but it is worst case

Comment: @rJ7 JS would be serious overkill for this...

Comment: Exactly what does **half a pixel** look like?

Comment: @Paulie_D the same as `1px` after you've applied `transform: scaleX(50)` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `:active` state selector. Basically, you can either add a `border` on the bottom **or** create a `pseudo-element` for this image's child (because not all browsers support `:before` and `:after` on images).

Border solution:

```
.image:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanna add an border at the bottom of your image on css like :

```
.image:active {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #123;
}
```